# .NET Core - JSonReaderException Error reading Jobject from JsonReader

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jsonreader

I'm developing an application with the ASP.NET core Framework and Visual Studio keeps coming up with the error message:

> **System.FormatException:** "Could not parse the JSON file. Error on line number '10':*/'." JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from
>   JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: Comment. Path ",
>   line 10, position 2.

The error occurs when I run the application and it tries to call the function `CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();`

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();        
}
```

That's strange, because I did not modify any Json-files and when using another device (laptop for mobile developing) on the same git-commit I do not get any error messages.

Does anybody maybe know which file the error message is referring to? I would really like to fix this on this specific machine...

This is the appsettings.json file:

```
{
   "ConnectionStrings":{
      "DefaultConnection":"Filename=./../database_02.db"
   },
   "Logging":{
      "LogLevel":{
         "Default":"Warning"
      }
   },
   "AllowedHosts":"*"
}
```

Comment: check your `appsettings.json`, seems that it's invalid

Comment: What's the JSON?